# dealing with un-executable commands inside a shell-script

Tags: shell-script, io

I am given an assignment like this: Write a Bash script that takes a *.tex file as command-line argument and checks if the file executes correctly without any errors. If it executes without any error and warning, assign a mark of 2 to that file. (1 mark if it compiled with a warning, and 0 marks if it shows an error).

I am able to assign marks for files which executed without any warnings and for files which gave a warning. Here, I am giving some of the lines of my code,

```
#!/bin/bash
rm t.txt
pdflatex $1 >> t.txt
message=`tail -2 t.txt|grep -i "output"|cut -c 1-6`
```

After executing the command `pdflatex`, my script searches for appropriate words like "output" and "warning", and accordingly assigns marks. But in the case of a file which has errors, the `pdflatex` command exits only if we give a 'x'. Since it is expecting an 'x' from the user, it waits there. If I run the script, it is not showing any output; but if I print an x, it assigns the mark to that file as zero.

But I have to give this program to an automatic code-evaluator which checks for my code, and tells if my code is correct for all the cases...

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Workaround: tell `pdflatex` to behave, using `-interaction nonstopmode`.

Answer (score 1):

Tell pdflatex not to wait for any interactive input ever:

```
pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode "$1"
```

If the command returns a nonzero status (`$?`), there was an error, so the mark is 0. Otherwise, test whether the log file (like `$1`, but with `.log` instead of the extension that's there already) contains the word `Warning`; if it does, the mark is 1, otherwise the mark is 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, if you have a program in a shell script that tries to read input from the user, you can stop that by adding this at the top of your script:

```
exec < /dev/null
```

This tells the script to read input from /dev/null instead of from the keyboard.  If any command after that tries to read input, it will immediately receive end-of-file.